Propagation delay stability
I have been asked to find out propagation delay stability for LVDS --> LVDS splitter. I can see the values for propagation delay Min, Typ and Max in the component datasheets. For example part 8SLVS1118NLGI has propagation delay of Typ-290ps and max-400ps.
I was unable to obtain this value from manufacturer. So propagation delay stability is the variation from min to max propagation delay ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Propagation delay is different from chip to chip. One piece can have 260ps, another one 300ps. Stability of single chip propagation delay will be temperature dependent.

Hello Michal, Thank you for the reply, So then i believe manufacture should provide these information about the variation up to device working temperature?

From datasheet information manufacturer guarantees you that any individual chip at any temperature between -40 to 85°C will have propagation delay under 400ps. Nothing more is said there and it is only up to manufacturer to choose which parameters will characterize, gaurantee or publish. These values are often "conservative" with enough margin. That means you probably never find chip or conditions when it reaches close to maximum (400ps). Stability of delay isn't characterized at all. You have to measure it yourself. But probably it will be much smaller then overall limit (up to 400ps).

Thank you for the explanation Michal. I will consider the value, max - typ PD (Maximum stability variation) for my design for now.
